# Column value change when manually assign in csv files pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The objective is when I manually insert a value of '$0' or '$0.00' in 'Body' column, it will automatically assign the 'Double' column value of 1.

```
Body                       Double     UNI
Hey Mark                     0         0
$0.00                        1         0
%0                           1         0
Hi John                      0         0
你好                         0         1
```

Now, I already write a code that if 'Body' column starts with $0/$0.00, will assign column 'Double' to 1. If the 'Body' does not start with either $0/$0.00, and if adding the additional string “$0/$0.00” in front of the 'Body' changes the number of parts in a 'Body', set the 'Double' value to 1.

```
df['Double'] = "0"
df.loc[df['Body'].str.startswith('$0', na=False),'Double'] = '1'
df.loc[df['Body'].str.startswith('$0.00', na=False),'Double'] = '1'
```

However, I tried to use with `.str.contains()` , yet when I opened the csv files, the column Double seems doesn't change to 1.

```
#if Column Body contains $0 / $0.00
#df.loc[df['Body'].str.contains('$0.00', na=False),'Double'] = '1'
#df.loc[df['Body'].str.contains('$0', na=False),'Double'] = '1'
```

I appreciate your help and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `$` is special regex char, end of string. So one possible solution is add `regex=False` parameter:

```
df.loc[df['Body'].str.contains('$0.00', na=False, regex=False),'Double'] = '1'
df.loc[df['Body'].str.contains('$0', na=False, regex=False),'Double'] = '1'
```

Or escape by `\`:

```
df.loc[df['Body'].str.contains('\$0.00', na=False),'Double'] = '1'
df.loc[df['Body'].str.contains('\$0', na=False),'Double'] = '1'
```

Better is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and join both strings by `|` for regex `or`:

```
df['Double'] = np.where(df['Body'].str.contains('\$0.00|\$0', na=False), '1', '0')
```

Original solution is possible with tuple of strings:

```
df['Double'] = np.where(df['Body'].str.startswith(('$0.00', '$0'), na=False), '1', '0')
```